# Is MVVM more necessary/important to Silverlight/WPF than MVP to Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, mvvm

I hope the title reflects what I'm really asking.  It seems to me that when people undertake `XAML` based development whether to use `MVVM` is not even a question, rather an understood fact.  Coming from a background of Winforms and Webforms, I found that we almost never used `MVP` (for example).  It was well understood that the main reasons to go down the `MVP` path (other than being a purist) is higher level of unit testing, and the ability to share "view logic" with different UIs.  As far as the later is concerned, it has never been a requirement in my projects.  If anything we might have had several user controls for this purpose.

As far as unit testing, I never found it necessary to test my `code behind` because it did nothing more than handle UI events and act as a proxy (create instance of and bind) to my business layer.  I can understand if people bypass the business layer and create instances of their favorite data access layer directly in the code behind, then apply business logic to it right there, where MVP would be a huge benefit.  In my cause I always front the DAL with a BLL, so where is the real "win" here as far as unit testing?

Point being it was never automatic to use MVP.  I am now looking at possibly using Sliverlight (for the first time) in a project and I feel like I'm going to be committing a sin if I don't use MVVM.

I know there are a slew of little things that are MVVM specific perhaps that were not a consideration before when I was making the "to MVP or not to MVP" decision.  I've read about Blend support (I don't even have Blend), maybe some other important aspects?  The bottom line is though, is MVVM really that much more important to Silverlight than MVP was to Webforms for example?  Or are we riding the renaissance days of .NET development where patterns and best practices are taking center stage (sort of like Java).

Answer (score 2):

We moved from Vb.Net winforms to C# and WPF/Silverlight under MVVM. It is definitely a change of pace from our adhock coding. I love being able to create multiple views to work with the same view model. Makes it easy to customize screens for our customers that want it without a whole lot of programming changes.

I found these posts in Stack Overflow that might answer your questions:

[Benefits of MVVM over MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593976/benefits-of-mvvm-over-mvc)

[Why MVVM and what are it's core benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644453/why-mvvm-and-what-are-its-core-benefits)

[MVVM Unique Benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602685/mvvm-unique-benefits)

Those have some good answers comparing MVP to MVVM.

Hope that helps.

**** Additionally **

If you were referring to Expression Blend, I used blend when I first learned xaml. Now that I know what I am doing in it, I rarely use it unless I need to do something complicated with animation or whatnot. I use visual studio for coding it since, from my experience, Blend is still cumbersome. Don't get me wrong, it's a great program and does animations great, but it's for designers, not coders really.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited experience with WPF and MVVM, my opinion is this:

MVVM is a pattern, but is not the end-all-be-all of WPF. Especially in the case of MVVM "purists." There are times and places for event handlers and code behind, even in WPF. The benefit of the xaml development and MVVM is the separation of logic from design, but at times, you logic involves your design much more directly than MVVM allows.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main reason why MVVM is so advocated because of the power of DataBinding.

With web forms for example, you will need to create your own interfaces, framework etc... to implement MVP, whereas in Silverlight/WPF, databinding is just there, so whether or not you use it, it is up to you.

In my opinion, I think MVVM simply adds in a layer of testable view logic (ViewModel) instead of like the MVP pattern where your business logic can really be in the presenter itself.

In summary, if it is already there, easy to use, use it.. it is like you have a car, but u can still choose to walk 10miles to your nearest market, or you can drive (most would advocate you to drive).

Thats my 2 cents.